# Maven "Failed to create assembly" Problem

Tags: plugins, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I use a very simple assembly desriptor:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>domain/etc/scripts/</directory>
        <outputDirectory>tools</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.bat</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

But I get all the time the following Error:
"Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive test: You must set at least one file" I also get this message if I execute maven with -e

**BUT!** The files where transfered to the "tools" directory! I don't understand why I get an error but the files are in the directory... I use "mvn assembly:single" goal

Can somebody try to explain it :) I also use assembly Plugin in the other Module but it works pretty fine.

Comment: Why don't you use simply mvn clean package ? Can you show the pom ?

Comment: I think I solved my problem. Well, this is a multi module project and simple usage of filesets doesn't work here :) It still doesn't work properly but I think I have found the right way (moduleSets)